# How to set left and right message side in chat?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, chat

I use https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController

For example, I send message from Send button(self user), I want that all this messages will be in right side. Then I receive message from users,  I want that this messages be from left side.

I find only that method to customize messages, but it not possible to use it with indexPath.

```
 - (JSBubbleMessageType)messageTypeForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return (sender == kSelf) ? JSBubbleMessageTypeIncoming : JSBubbleMessageTypeOutgoing;
}
```

Comment: try this one https://github.com/Tech-Dev-Mobile/IOS-Message-Chat

Comment: Did you read their documentation? Or try their sample project? https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController/blob/master/JSMessagesDemo/JSDemoViewController.m

Comment: @Marc Mosby, yep, I comment your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have to store all messages in an array.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *messages;
```

This array stores all message objects (of type `JSMessage`). You can then use the indexPath in the delegate method to find the message object

```
JSMessage *message = self.messages[indexPath.row];
NSString *sender = message.sender;

return (sender == kSelf) ? JSBubbleMessageTypeIncoming : JSBubbleMessageTypeOutgoing;
```

Comment: I use it for storied messages, my problem is that this code not works with messages that came after loading from array, that code note sort my new messages to right side and messages of other user to left side. I tried to write a lot of sorters for sender of message but all that not works=/

Comment: hi @Marc have u worked with JSQMessagesViewController i need a help from u